# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on .... Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am calling the webservice which is deployed on another tomcat server. I am getting the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.200.85:8080/Test/webapi/GetCustomerProfile?accountNo=81701. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

following is my webservice code:

```
 import com.ef.wrapupcodes.Skills.ServiceData;

 package com.ef.wrapupcodes;

 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

 import com.ef.wrapupcodes.Skills.ServiceData;

   @Path("/services/{serviceName}")
   public class GetSG
   {
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response  GetSkillGroups(@PathParam ("serviceName") String serName)
   {    
    Skills services = new Skills(serName);
    ServiceData list = services.getServices(); 
    final GenericEntity<ServiceData> outPut = 
     new GenericEntity<ServiceData>       (list) { };

    return Response.ok()
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS")
            .status(200).entity(outPut).build();
    }

    }
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add  this code :

```
return Response.ok()
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
  .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With").build();
```

another solution (create class implement ContainerResponseFilter )

```
   @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest creq, ContainerResponse cresp) {

        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cresp.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

        return cresp;
    }
```

in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>CORS Filter</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>your.package.CORSFilter</param-value>
 </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CORS Filter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Your solution is working for me but there is something missing in your giving solution. the working code is 
return Response.ok()
         .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
         .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS")
         .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
         .status(200).entity(outPut).build();